How to test potentiometer with 4 In Line terminals
I need to test 3 identical Claro potentiometers that have 4 In Line terminals, (not 3 together and one elsewhere as others have asked about).
These are Claro EPVR/341 potentiometers that are also marked 20 0333 CLARO CCW N CW T MEXICO.  Wire Colors are Mauve Green Orange Gray.
The potentiometers are all made to move and work in both directions i.e. UP - DOWN   and LEFT - RIGHT.
Need to know connections for using multimeter for testing.

Claro = Clarostat, now Honeywell. You may be able to find a datasheet, or else, just measure the resistances between the pins to figure it out.

You will not damage either the multimeter or the potentiometer by just connecting up to different combinations of the terminals and seeing which ones have a varying resistance when you move the knob/joystick.

Thank you for that.  I just tested two of the potentiometers and of the 6 combinations of the four terminals you can test, they both tested exactly the same, (the same 3 working and 3 not), so I would assume they are both OK, as doubtful they would both fail in exactly the same way.   I'll test the third tomorrow and advise if any difference.
